# InnoSetup Chainned installers MSI file

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

I made an installer with InnoSetup and I need to run some msi files after the normal instalation.
I added the next lines of code:

```
[Files]
Source: "..\..\..\Dependencies\sqlncli2012.msi"; DestDir: "{tmp}"
Source: "..\..\..\Dependencies\SQLSysClrTypes.msi"; DestDir: "{tmp}"
Source: "..\..\..\Dependencies\SQLServer2012_XMO.msi"; DestDir: "{tmp}"
Source: "..\..\..\Dependencies\SqlCmdLnUtils.msi"; DestDir: "{tmp}"


[Run]
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES""{tmp}\sqlncli2012.msi"" /qb"; StatusMsg: Installing MySQL Server;
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\SQLSysClrTypes.msi"" /qb"
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\SQLServer2012_XMO.msi"" /qb"
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\SqlCmdLnUtils.msi"" /qb"
```

I have seen there is a similar question but I just can't figure out what I did wrong.
I made a fresh install of windows 7 in a virtual machine and I get the following errors:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzckS.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJoRC.png

As you can see I get error at the last msi file, SqlCmdLnUtils, and the ones before do not even start. (I also tested without "IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES" and I get the following error "The required IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES command-line parameter is missing. By specifying this parameter...),so the fact that the installation file does not exists drops.)

Comment: Does the same happen if you run that SQLServer2012_XMO.msi installation command from command prompt ? The second error reports that you're missing yet SQL Server Native Client, so I guess you'll need to include it in your setup chain as well. But better use the `PrepareToInstall` event for installing all those packages.

Comment: If i was running from command prompt worked fine so that's how I figured I maybe needed to remove the qb (basic UI). Sql Server Native Client is the first one, sqlncli. I don't knot how to use PrepareToInstall so for now I will leave it like this. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this by removing the "/qb" which means Basic UI, so by default will be Full UI and by moving files from {tmp} to {app} folder but I don't think that is necesarry.

```
Source: "..\..\..\Dependencies\sqlncli2012.msi"; DestDir: "{app}\Installation Files";
Source: "..\..\..\Dependencies\SQLSysClrTypes.msi"; DestDir: "{app}\Installation Files";
Source: "..\..\..\Dependencies\SQLServer2012_XMO.msi"; DestDir: "{app}\Installation Files"
Source: "..\..\..\Dependencies\SqlCmdLnUtils.msi"; DestDir: "{app}\Installation Files"


[Run]
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{app}\Installation Files\sqlncli2012.msi"; StatusMsg: Installing SQL Server Native Client;
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{app}\Installation Files\SQLSysClrTypes.msi"; StatusMsg: Installing SQL SysClrTypes;
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{app}\Installation Files\SQLServer2012_XMO.msi"; StatusMsg: Installing SQL Server XMO;
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{app}\Installation Files\SqlCmdLnUtils.msi"; StatusMsg: Installing SQL CmdLnUtils;
```